# Can I transfer money with a Paypal account of incomplete status?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal

[image: Paypal Status]

Can I transfer money to my friend? What's the difference between send and transfer money?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send money, but you will have a limit on the amount. The benefits you get with a Basic or Verified status include higher limits.

PayPal seem to only make a distinction between paying for goods, and sending money to friends - the difference is around your protection as a consumer.